# How do you pass a JQuery object in a function as a parameter for that object's method call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have a method `showTable` that takes a JQuery object, and the `showTable` call is a parameter for the `append` method of that same object.

This is the result I'm going for:

```
body.append (this.showTable(body));
```

`showTable` returns an HTML string to append to `body`. But I don't like typing `body` twice, it feels clunky. How do make it implicit that `body` is the variable to be passed?

Comment: doesn't feel clunky to me...

Comment: why don't you just do the `.append` within the `showTable` function?

Comment: also, why does `showTable` care about what `body` is at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [.append( function(index, html) )](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-functionindex--html) variant here

```
body.append (this.showTable);
```

then inside

```
function showTable(){
    //here this points to the body element
}
```

Comment: @Alnitak from the doc `Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set` did I misunderstand it

Comment: no, I think your right, I upvoted the comment, then thought about it and `$(this)` will be the body.

Comment: ah, ok, a special case I didn't know about - it seems that `.append` will indeed set the context if you pass it a function reference.  However note that it will be set to the current jQuery element, and not whatever the value of `this` was when you referenced `this.showTable`, that being the mistake most people make when they pass a reference to a member function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by rewriting it in fluent style:

```
this.showTable(body).appendTo(body)
```

But that doesn't really answer the question. I think it looks better.

To answer the question, I would write a helper function:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    appendTableTo: function(thing) { return this.showTable(thing).appendTo(thing) }
});
this.appendTableTo(body);
```